# Install Slackware on a USB Pendrive

Tags: linux, boot, usb, slackware

I have a nice, smooth flash drive which requires a mounting of a DVD ISO image for Slackware to install. For whatever reason, Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator refuses to notice the iso, so I can't use that. Thus, I have to do it the hard way.

Before anyone mentions [this](http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=slackware%3ausbboot#boot_disk_on_a_mini_usb_image), I'd like to mention that I already have looked into that and unfortunately it's not quite what I'm looking for. I need to mount the entire DVD iso image of slackware, not a small 37 mb image for USB.

Is this possible at all in Ubuntu? Many please and thank yous.

Comment: It refuses to recognise it because Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator is only designed to put its *own* startup disks on USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create bootable USB drives for many Linux distros